# Fitting mixed model with interactions between two categorical variables using glmmTMB

Tags: r, mixed-models, interaction, model-fitting, glmmtmb

Usually my mixed models contain several categorical variables with a lot of unique levels, so `X` matrix is ​​very sparse.
I use `glmmTMB` package that handles `X` and `Z` matrices as sparse. This significantly reduced RAM usage during fitting the model.
The `glmmTMB` package is great, but there is one problem for me (maybe I'm missing something):
when I use **interactions** between a **numeric variable** and a **categorical variable** (as FE), the model is fitted without errors.
For example, this model works well:

```
fit = glmmTMB(Y ~ 0 + num1:factor1 + num2:factor1 + factor2 + 
(0 + num3|subject) + (0 + num4|subject) + (1|subject), 
model_data, REML = TRUE, sparseX=c(cond=TRUE))
```

But when I use any **interactions** between **two categorical variables** i.e. the formula looks like this:

```
fit = glmmTMB(Y ~ 0 + num1:factor1 + factor3:factor1 + factor2 + 
(0 + num2|subject) + (0 + num3|subject) + (1|subject), 
model_data, REML = TRUE, sparseX=c(cond=TRUE)),
```

I get the following error:

```
iter: 5  Error in newton(par = c(beta = 1, beta = 1, beta = 1, beta = 1, beta = 1,  : 
  Newton failed to find minimum.
In addition: Warning message:
In (function (start, objective, gradient = NULL, hessian = NULL,  :
  NA/NaN function evaluation
outer mgc:  NaN 
Error in (function (start, objective, gradient = NULL, hessian = NULL,  : 
  gradient function must return a numeric vector of length 4
```

At the same time, in mixed model theory, interactions between two categorical variables are valid.
Moreover, such model (with interactions between two factors) is successfully fitted with `Julia` `MixedModels` package.

Could you help me, please, to understand root of this error?
Is there a way to avoid it in a model with interactions between two categorical variables?
Why does such models work with `Julia MixedModels` and not work with `glmmTMB`?